# SharePoint Remote Event Receiver for Provider Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am really struggling to setup a RER for my provider hosted app.
whatever I do the receiver is not getting fired.

There are good instructions available for other app types, but not for REM for provider hosted apps.

Can anyone help????

Answer (score 1):

First check that is your RER hit on debug mode.
For that at the bottom of the SharePoint properties page, select the 'Enable remote event debugging' check box.
and do not forget to add 'WPW3' processes while debugging.

Please  follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn275975.aspx

Comment: Must admit that your answer is correct given the question, however I had already done your suggestions and I was still struggling. What I was really after was: how to set-up IIS, how to set-up SharePoint and how to set-up the actually MVC app